# How to access index inside function for applymap in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using a custom function in pandas that iterates over cells in a dataframe, finds the same row in a different dataframe, extracts it as a tuple, extracts a random value from that tuple, and then adds a user specified amount of noise to the value and returns it to the original dataframe.  I was hoping to find a way to do this that uses `applymap`, is it possible? I couldn't find a way using `applymap`, so I used `itertuples`, but an `applymap` solution should be more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
# Mock data creation
key = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4,5,6], 'col3':[7,8,9]})
results = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)))

def apply_value(value):    
    key_index = # <-- THIS IS WHERE I NEED A WAY TO ACCESS INDEX
    key_tup = key.iloc[key_index]
    length = (len(key_tup) - 1)
    random_int = random.randint(1, length)
    random_value = key_tup[random_int]
    return random_value

results = results.applymap(apply_value)
```

Comment: Existing Q&A: [Using Pandas to "applymap" with access to index/column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773833/using-pandas-to-applymap-with-access-to-index-column), [Pandas - get row and column name for each element during applymap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654727/pandas-get-row-and-column-name-for-each-element-during-applymap)

Comment: a) Your code boils down to just doing `np.random.choice(key_tup)` b) You need to fix your example data, if `key` is really supposed to be a dataframe of tuples (not just values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, this piece of code should work. The problem is that `applymap` does not hold the index of the dataframe, so what you have to do is to apply nested `apply` functions: the first iterates over rows, and we get the key from there, and the second iterates over columns in each row. Hope it helps. Let me know if it does :D

```
# Mock data creation
key = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4,5,6], 'col3':[7,8,9]})
results = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)))
def apply_value(value, key_index):
    key_tup= key.loc[key_index]
    length = (len(key_tup) - 1)
    random_int = random.randint(1, length)
    random_value = key_tup[random_int]
    return random_value
results = results.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda d: apply_value(d, x.name)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly you don't need to access row-index inside your function, there are other simpler ways to implement this.
You can probably do without it entirely, you don't even need do a pandas JOIN/merge of rows of `key`.
But first, you need to fix your example data, if `key` is really supposed to be a dataframe of tuples.

So you want to:

- sweep over each column with `apply(... , axis=1)`
- lookup the value of each cell `key.loc[key_index]`...
- ...which is supposed to give you a tuple `key_tup`, but in your example `key` was a simple dataframe, not a dataframe of tuples
- key_tup = key.iloc[key_index]
- the business with:

```
    length = (len(key_tup) - 1)
    random_int = random.randint(1, length)
    random_value = key_tup[random_int]
```

- can be simplified to just:

```
np.random.choice(key_tup)
```

- in which case you likely don't need to declare `apply_value()`